# How to clear Notification from GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

i am developing one application that i have to receive  Notification  from gcm server i received notification successfully here have two problems.

1) i successfully read more than one notification but all messages notifications shows only one message shows only i.e last data only .

2) whenever open notifcation that Notication icon on notice bar will not be gone.i wrote the code for remove notification its not working please help me.

### my GcmIntentService code

```
 public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService{
    Context context;
    public static  int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    public static final String TAG = "GCM Demo";

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String msg = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

         if (!extras.isEmpty()) {

             if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                        MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                    sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
                } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                        MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                    sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " +
                            extras.toString());
                // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
                } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                        MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                    // This loop represents the service doing some work.
                    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i+1)
                                + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        }
                    }
                    Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    // Post notification of received message.
                    //sendNotification("Received: " + extras.toString());
                    sendNotification(msg);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
                }
            }
         GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


        Intent myintent = new Intent(this, ReceiveActivity.class);
        myintent.putExtra("message", msg);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                myintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)
        .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
        .bigText(msg))
        .setContentText(msg);

      /*  NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle =
                new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
        String[] events = new String[6];
        // Sets a title for the Inbox style big view
        inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle("Event tracker details:");

        int numMessages = 0;

        // Moves events into the big view
        for (int i=0; i < events.length; i++) {

            inboxStyle.addLine(events[i]);
        }

        mBuilder.setStyle(inboxStyle);
        */
        AudioManager am = (AudioManager)this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        /* Even if the mode is set to "Sound & Vibration" in the phone, 
         * the status code that getRingerMode() returns is RINGER_MODE_NORMAL.
         */
        switch (am.getRingerMode()) 
        {
            case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
                mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
                break;
            case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
                mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
                break;
            default:
                mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
         }


        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        // TO clear notification

        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID++, mBuilder.build());

        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                 .bigText(msg))
                .setContentText(msg);
        mNotificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);

    }

   }
```

**my Receive Activity**

```
 package com.technowellServices.locationfind;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ReceiveActivity extends Activity {
    TextView name;
    TextView deal;
    TextView valid;
    TextView address;
    JSONObject json;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_receive);
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    deal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.deal);
    valid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.valid);
    address = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.address);
    String message = intent.getExtras().getString("message");
    try {
        json = new JSONObject(message);
        String stime = json.getString("name");
        name.setText(stime);

        String slecturename = json.getString("deal");
        deal.setText(slecturename);

        String sroom = json.getString("valid");
        valid.setText(sroom);

        String sfaculty = json.getString("address");
        address.setText(sfaculty);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



      }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

please add this method and pass your notification id in this method..
this method is called in on resume method on your main activity..

```
public void CancelNotification(Context ctx, int notifyId) {
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(ns);
        nMgr.cancel(notifyId);
    }
```

I hope its useful to you.

Comment: thank you for replay i wrote notification id in IntentService class than how i call this method in my Receive activity with notification id

Comment: please add onresume() in ReceiveActivity .and call above method in onresume().

Comment: thank you its ok but what about my first question i received all notifications with same data i.e last sent data from server.please help me..

Comment: check this one:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Answer (score 0):

please check this code:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
    .setContentTitle("Event tracker")
    .setContentText("Events received")
NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle =
        new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
String[] events = new String[6];
// Sets a title for the Inbox style big view
inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle("Event tracker details:");
...
// Moves events into the big view
for (int i=0; i < events.length; i++) {

    inboxStyle.addLine(events[i]);
}
// Moves the big view style object into the notification object.
mBuilder.setStyle(inBoxStyle);
...
// Issue the notification here.
```

please check this

[reference link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

i hope its helpful to you.

Comment: i used this one its not work for me that way i using mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID++, mBuilder.build());

Comment: please comment this line

Comment: // Because the ID remains unchanged, the existing notification is
    // updated.
    mNotificationManager.notify(
            notifyID,
            mNotifyBuilder.build());

Comment: @Durga if you have use same notification id then new notification update old one.if you use different notification id for all times then its display all notification.you also pass notification id same as message content...r u getting?

Comment: ok but how to use different notification id.s for every time?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48228/discussion-between-durga-and-dipali)

Answer (score 0):

That's incorrect :

```
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID++, mBuilder.build());

    mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
             .bigText(msg))
            .setContentText(msg);
    mNotificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
```

You don't have to create another notification builder for cancelling the notification. You simply have to call `mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)` for the original builder before calling `mNotificationManager.notify`.

Therefore you should replace that code with :

```
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID++, mBuilder.build());
```